# Swift (for in) immutable value

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a function within the ViewController class. I want to loop through a string and count the number of times a specific character occurs. Code looks like this:

```
var dcnt:Int = 0
func decimalCount(inputvalue: String) -> Int {
    for chr in inputvalue.characters {
        if chr == “.” { 
            ++dcnt
        }
    }
    return dcnt
}
```

The input string comes from a UILabel!

I get a warning: Immutable value ‘chr’ was never used.

How can I fix this problem

Comment: Xcode 7 even displays a "Fix-it" on the next line: *unicode curly quote found, replace with '"'* ... You only have to confirm the suggestion.

Comment: that took away my ability to compare the array element with "."

Answer (score 3):

The problem, as so often in Swift, lies elsewhere. It's the curly quotes. Put this:

```
if chr == "." {
```

Comment: By the way, there is a much better way to write this function as one-liner: `return inputvalue.characters.filter{$0=="."}.count` Any time you catch yourself accumulating values in a variable (array, counter, whatever) in Swift, you should suspect there's a Better Way.

Comment: Nice solution to problem.  I wish I understood why the variable chr was immutable on the (for in) line

Comment: I explained that. It's Swift misleading you.